FastAPI Custom Router Class - How to get All Router Function Input Parameters
Is there a way to get the input parameters for a fastapi APIRoute function when defining a custom router class (per the docs)?
For example, in the example below, if the things variable wasn't sent in the request, could I still get a hold of the value passed to it in my custom router class?
from typing import List, Callable

from fastapi import Body, FastAPI, Request, Response
from fastapi.routing import APIRoute


class CustomRoute(APIRoute):
    def get_route_handler(self) -> Callable:
        original_route_handler = super().get_route_handler()

        async def custom_route_handler(request: Request) -> Response:

            # HOW CAN I GET THE INPUTS TO sum_numbers FUNCTION HERE?

            _r = await original_route_handler(request)

            return _r

        return custom_route_handler


def create_app():
    app = FastAPI()
    app.router.route_class = CustomRoute

    return app


app = create_app()


@app.post("/sum")
async def sum_numbers(numbers: List[int] = Body(), things: str = "stuff"):
    return {"sum": sum(numbers), "things": things}


In your custom_route_handler function, you are receiving the request as is.
It is exactly the same fastapi.Request instance you will normally get in any other non-custom route as well.
What you can do here is simply access the request.body right in the line where you commented in all caps.
Here's the snippet:
    # ... truncated ...

    async def custom_route_handler(request: Request) -> Response:

        body = await request.body() # <- this is how

        _r = await original_route_handler(request)

        return _r

    # ... truncated ...

